# Default values in structure

Tags: c, queue, conditional-statements, runtime-error

I am getting a runtime error if i use the condition q->head==NULL && q->tail==NULL instead of q->head==NULL for the enqueue in empty list, while both the conditions shall suffice. Can anyone tell me the fault? I am providing the entire code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct node Node;
typedef Node* NODE;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct queue Queue;
typedef Queue* QUEUE;
struct queue{
    NODE head;
    NODE tail;
};    

void initQueue(QUEUE q);
void enqueue(QUEUE q,int key);
void dequeue(QUEUE q);
void print(QUEUE q);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QUEUE q;
    initQueue(q);
    //print(q);
    dequeue(q);
    enqueue(q,7);

    enqueue(q,9);
    print(q);
    dequeue(q);
    print(q);
    return 0;
}


void initQueue(QUEUE q){
    q=(QUEUE)malloc(sizeof(Queue)*1);
    q->head=NULL;
    q->tail=NULL;
}

void enqueue(QUEUE q,int key){
    NODE temp;
    temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(Node)*1);
    temp->data=key;
    temp->next=NULL;

    if(q->head==NULL && q->tail==NULL){
        q->head=temp;
        q->tail=temp;
    }
    else{
        q->tail->next=temp;
        q->tail=temp;
    }

}//end of enqueue()

void dequeue(QUEUE q){
    NODE temp;
    if(q->head==NULL){
        printf("queue is empty");
    }
    else{
        temp=q->head;
        q->head=temp->next;
        free(temp);    
    }
}

void print(QUEUE q){
    NODE cur;
    if(q->head==NULL){
        printf("Queue is empty!\n");
    }
    else{
        cur=q->head;

        while(cur!=NULL){
            printf("%d",cur->data);
            cur=cur->next;

        }//end of while    
    }//end of else    
}//end of print
```

Comment: I would also suggest that you accept some answers to your other questions...

Comment: Consider dropping some or all of the `typedef`s.  Using `queue` as the struct tag, `Queue` as an alias for `struct queue`, *and* `QUEUE` as an alias for `pointer to struct queue` is just confusing.  Typedefs for structs are common practice (but you can use the same identifier: `typedef struct queue queue;`), but typedefs for pointer types are potentially dangerous.  Using pointer syntax explicitly forces you to be aware that you're working with pointers.  For example, I'd write `void initQueue(struct queue *q);`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what the problem is. In `dequeue`, q->head will at some point become NULL. **But `q->tail` still points to some bogus address**!

```
void dequeue(QUEUE q){
    NODE temp;
    if(q->head==NULL){
        printf("queue is empty");
    }
    else{
        temp=q->head;
        q->head=temp->next;
        free(temp);    
    }
}
```

Then, in your enqueue, `q->head` is `NULL` but `q->tail` points to some invalid address (the old tail).

```
if(q->head==NULL && q->tail==NULL)
```

So it won't enter that `if` and instead it will try `q->tail->next=temp;` which is **undefined** since `t->tail` was freed.

Comment: I removed the comment immediately after looking more into the code! :)

Comment: +1 As this will also become a problem later on. I don't think it'll cause any problems with the simple test given in the OP though (as the queue isn't emptied and then reused by the code).

Answer (score 2):

You should always compile with all warnings enabled:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -W -pedantic -std=c99 q.c
q.c: In function ‘main’:
q.c:25:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
q.c:25:27: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
q.c:27:14: warning: ‘q’ is used uninitialized in this function
```

The first two warnings you can ignore (for now), but the third hints at your problem.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QUEUE q;
    initQueue(q);

[snip]

void initQueue(QUEUE q){
    q=(QUEUE)malloc(sizeof(Queue)*1);
```

In `initQueue` you're modifying the local `QUEUE` (which is a pointer) `q` rather than the one in `main`.

Either change the signature of `initQueue` to take a `QUEUE*` and use `*q` in that function or do the following:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QUEUE q;
    q = initQueue();

[snip]

QUEUE initQueue(){
    QUEUE q=(QUEUE)malloc(sizeof(Queue)*1);
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
    return q;
}
```